# Regex match group of words and parenthesis after comma

Tags: python, regex, split, regex-group

I've got an string like this:

```
aaaa (aa), bbbb, b2b2b2 (bbbb), ccc, c33 (ccc), ddd, d222, d33 (ddd)
```

And I want to split it to extract every group after the comma followed by the parentheses:

```
aaaa (aa)
bbbb, b2b2b2 (bbbb)
ccc, c33 (ccc)
ddd, d222, d33 (ddd)
```

I tried several regex expressions,  even the [Parse library](https://pypi.org/project/parse/), but without success

Any idea would be welcomed!!

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Please post the attempt(s), see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Lookbehind

**Ex:**

```
import re

s = "aaaa (aa), bbbb, b2b2b2 (bbbb), ccc, c33 (ccc), ddd, d222, d33 (ddd)"
print(re.split(r"(?<=\)),", s))
```

**Output:**

```
['aaaa (aa)', ' bbbb, b2b2b2 (bbbb)', ' ccc, c33 (ccc)', ' ddd, d222, d33 (ddd)']
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't how we can do it by regex but a very simple one liner is here:

```
string = '''aaaa (aa), bbbb, b2b2b2 (bbbb), ccc, c33 (ccc), ddd, d222, d33 (ddd)'''
[i.strip().strip()+")"  if ")" not in i else i.strip() for i in string.split("),")]
```

which gives:

```
['aaaa (aa)', 'bbbb, b2b2b2 (bbbb)', 'ccc, c33 (ccc)', 'ddd, d222, d33 (ddd)']
```